# subscription does not ready while subscribe to another

Tags: meteor, iron-router

For example

```
Router.route('/:username/posts', {
  waitOn: function() {
    //Meteor.subscribe(('user', this.params.username));  // A
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: this.params.username}); // B
    if(user) {
      return Meteor.subscribe('posts', user._id);
    }
  }
});
```

if I directly input `http://localhost/userA/posts` in the address bar of Chrome and enter, when code goes to B, at that time, Meteor.users has not ready.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the user checking in the publish handler.
Like this:

```
Meteor.publish("posts", function (username) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: username});
    if (user) {
        return Posts.find({user: user._id});
    }
});
```